# just making sure i understand how perspective works in 3d Graphics

Tags: 3d

while i was able to go through the OpenGl tutorial i followed successfully, and finish all the chapters, i was still left in the grey about how perspective projection actually works. why is it the way it is.

i think i now understand and i just want to make sure i am correct. please let me know of anything i say is incorrect.

there are a few prerequisite principles that take play in reaching my final understanding of how it works:

1. gpus are made to run as optimally as possible, even if it means building the foundation of a graphics environment around its rigid and universal functionality
2. the w component often serves as a free slot to fit in constant values as part of the process of projecting with perspective.
3. the GPU does the division by w to all the vertices before working with them under the assumption they are with NDC now, meaning you can have vertices sent from the vertex shader that are outside of the theoretical NDC if the w component is bigger than 1.

these main 3 realizations help me finally grasp how perspective projection actually works, and why it is the way it is.

so the idea is that the projection matrix does not actually shift the space out of orthogonality, it just preps the coordinates to fit within the NDC after divided by their w component, essentially treating that division as the component that applies that non orthogonal shift into the "frustum" shape we are familiar with.

the most confusing part of the process for me to understand was "where does that frustum shape appear in the matrix?". the idea is that it does not appear in code, but implicitly happens by the GPU and we cause this to happen by manipulating the w component of the vector.

this means, applying a shift to the Z value, doesnt squish or stretch or distort anything, and multiplying the x and y components by the amount we want the final "fov" to appear, does not actually perform a non orthogonal distortion to space itself, it just makes sure that when the GPU gets the vector of the vertex, in combination of the very simple "w as z" component, they would all fall into place within the NDC BASED ON THE NEAR AND FAR PLANE for it to rasterize a view of the scene with perspective.

edit: another insight i was having is that the non linearity of the resulting depth values is also just a consequence of this approach, as it is also being divided by w, meaning all the projection matrix makes sure is that those divided values fall in a range between 0 and one based on the near and far planes. in theory, you could have a fully linear representation of the depth of vertices after they have been perspective shifted, but not only it would break colinearity of previously colinear coordinates, it would also be harder for gpu to work with as large ranges of distances woud be crammed closer together, increasing the z fighting in closer distance. its just a very elegant symbiosis

i tried to grasp this concept for the longest time, but now that i took another look at it, i hope i can finally say i get how it works.